# Eclipse (Luna) New xhtml Wizard missing

Tags: eclipse, jsf, facelets

I recently installed Eclipse (Luna) and Glassfish 4.1 as an attempt to write JSF.

When I created a new Dynamic Web Project and added a new index page, I had no "New xhtml" wizard" option. As the servlet mapping is defined in "web.xml" as:

```
...
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
...
```

I need to write xhtml pages for the project.

Anything I am missing?